# Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object

Tags: magento

When i am trying to add address of a customer through Admin panel it displays below error :

> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function setAttribute() on a
>   non-object in
>   **/home1/web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data.php**
>   on line **80**

[image]

How to solve this error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem,
solution from here: [Abstract/Data.php issue when checking out or creating account](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/vie/viewthread/289617/#t407061)

> 1. Please find customer_eav_attribute and note down all the attribute ids from this table.
> 2. Then find the eav_attribute table and check all the attribute id from this table.
> 3. Check the frontend_input column has not blank or null value of the attribute id which is got from the customer_eav_attribute table. 
>      4.If any attribute has blank or null value for the column frontend_input then add any of the input type in their place.
> 4. Then check the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Since links might become obsolete, please, add essential part of answer from link to your answer here.

Comment: Actually customer registration was working on my site some days ago,So what I did is copy two tables i.e customer_eav_attribute and eav_attribute from database backup and imported them in the present database by truncating the tables initially. So it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by many different attributes.

I added in Data.php on line 79 `var_dump($attribute->getAttributeCode());` and looked at the response after clicking save. In the database I search in the table `eav_attribute` for this attribute.

In my case the frontend_input was invalid. I changed it to "text", now it works.

Answer (score -1):

Add in (after adding one address but before pressing **save client**):

```
app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data.php - line 80 var_dump(get_class_methods($attribute));
exit;
```

And check in console on that request if in the list is there indeed this method `setAttribute()`